Azure Databricks Hadoop Streaming Error for Read From Apache Iceberg
We are building out a data lakehouse and upgrading our databricks runtime from 12.2 LTS to 14.3 LTS to support python 3.10. We are able to write into our iceberg tables, but reading those tables presents the following blocker where the hadoop byte buffer stream in trying to read out out:
Error: UnsupportedOperationException: Byte-buffer read unsupported by org.apache.hadoop.fs.BufferedFSInputStream org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (10.139.64.20 executor 1): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Byte-buffer read unsupported by org.apache.hadoop.fs.BufferedFSInputStream
Using the following runtime configs:
Azure databricks: 14.3 LTS runtime
apache iceberg: 1.5.2
spark: 3.5.0
scala: 2.12
azure-hadoop: 3.4.0
Anyone run into this issue?
databricks notebook code this is simplified as just a test versus our actual code:
#paragraph 1
pip install azure-storage-blob pymssql pymysql snowflake-connector-python

#paragraph 2
import datetime
import pymysql
import pymssql
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json
import re
import pandas as pd
import gzip
import shutil
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, ContainerClient, BlobServiceClient
from enum import Enum

# metadata info - all these vars are set in run
metadata_info = {
    "workflow_id": ,
    "workflow_name": "",
    "Terra_version": "",
    "stage_connection_name": "",
    "stage_schema": "",
    "host": "c", #cs.metadata_host, 
    "database": "",             #cs.metadata_database,
    "port": 3306,                                        #cs.metadata_port,
    "user_name": "",                        #cs.metadata_user_name,
    "password": "",                      #cs.metadata_passwd  
}

# cluster configuration
def init_spark_config(
    catalog_container: str,
    catalog_account: str,
    catalog_sas_token: str,
    catalog_name: str = "spark_catalog",
):
    conf = SparkConf()
    # following are needed for Spark/Hadoop/AzureBlob configuration
    # example setup https://medium.com/@rvaid.29/reading-and-writing-data-to-azure-blob-storage-using-pyspark-cc8ce2fd3470


    # in Databricks, these have to be set on compute cluster and appropriate jars needs to be loaded to cluster via init script or linked from maven repository
    conf.set(
        "spark.jars.packages",
        "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.4.0,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:8.6.6,org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.5.2",
    )
    conf.set(
        "spark.sql.extensions",
        "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions",
    )
    conf.set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "hive")
    conf.set(
        "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog",
        "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog",
    )
    conf.set(
        f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog_name}", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog"
    )
    conf.set(f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog_name}.type", "hadoop")

    # seems these can be adjusted later and per session
    conf.set(
        f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog_name}.warehouse",
        f"wasbs://{catalog_container}@{catalog_account}.blob.core.windows.net/{catalog_name}",
    )
    conf.set(
        f"spark.hadoop.fs.azure.sas.{catalog_container}.{catalog_account}.blob.core.windows.net",
        catalog_sas_token,
    )
    conf.set(
        f"fs.azure.sas.{catalog_container}.{catalog_account}.blob.core.windows.net",
        catalog_sas_token,
    )

    return conf

def get_storage_info(metadata, purpose: str):
  # query storage info
  if purpose == 'stage':
    query = f"""
      select c.connection_type, c.connection_details, c.password, '{{"stage_schema":"{metadata['stage_schema']}"}}' as storage_details
      from connection_details c
      where c.connection_name = '{metadata['stage_connection_name']}'
    """
  else:
    storageDetailsField = 'w.source_details'
    connectionIdField = 'connection_id'
    if purpose == 'target': 
      storageDetailsField = 'w.target_details'
      connectionIdField = 'target_connection_id'
    query = f"""
      select c.connection_type, c.connection_details, c.password, {storageDetailsField} as storage_details
      from connection_details c
      left join workflow_details w on json_value({storageDetailsField} , '$.{connectionIdField}') = c.connection_id
      where w.workflow_id = {metadata['workflow_id']}
    """
  conn = pymysql.connect(host = metadata['host']
                        ,port=metadata['port']
                        ,user = metadata['user_name']
                        ,password = metadata['password']
                        ,db = metadata['database']
                        ,charset='utf8mb4'
                        ,cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
  cursor = conn.cursor()  
  cursor.execute(query)
  conn_details=json.dumps(cursor.fetchone())
  conn.commit()
  cursor.close()
  conn.close()
  return json.loads(conn_details)

metadata = metadata_info
start_time = datetime.now()
source = get_storage_info(metadata_info, purpose="source")
stage = get_storage_info(metadata_info, purpose="stage")
target = get_storage_info(metadata_info, purpose="target")


sourceAccount = json.loads(source["connection_details"])[
    "Storage_Account_Name"
]
sourceContainer = json.loads(source["connection_details"])[
    "Container_Name"
]
sourceType = json.loads(source["storage_details"])["file_type"]
sourcePass = json.loads(source["connection_details"])["sas_token"]

stageAccount = json.loads(stage["connection_details"])[
    "Storage_Account_Name"
]
stageContainer = json.loads(stage["connection_details"])[
    "Container_Name"
]
stageSchema = json.loads(stage["storage_details"])["stage_schema"]
stagePass = json.loads(stage["connection_details"])["sas_token"]

targetType = json.loads(target["storage_details"])["target_type"]
targetSchema = json.loads(target["storage_details"])["target_schema"]
targetDatabase = json.loads(target["storage_details"])[
    "target_database"
]
targetServer = json.loads(target["connection_details"])["host"]
targetPort = json.loads(target["connection_details"])["port"]


conf = init_spark_config(
        catalog_container=stageContainer,
        catalog_account=stageAccount,
        catalog_sas_token=stagePass,
        catalog_name=stageSchema,
    )

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

# paragraph 3 
data = [("Raj", "10"), ("Mitch", "20")]

# Define schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Age", StringType(), True)
])

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

# Show DataFrame
df.show()

#paragraph 4
catalog_name = 'data_vault_lake.test'

def setup_spark_catalog(
    container_name: str, account_name: str, sas_token: str, catalog_name: str
):
    spark.conf.set(
        f"fs.azure.sas.{container_name}.{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", sas_token
    )
    spark.conf.set(
        f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog_name}", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog"
    )
    spark.conf.set(f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog_name}.type", "hadoop")
    spark.conf.set(
        f"spark.sql.catalog.{catalog_name}.warehouse",
        f"wasbs://{container_name}@{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{catalog_name}",
    )

#paragraph 5

tableName = 'writeTest1'
df.writeTo(f"{catalog_name}.{tableName}").using("iceberg").create()

#paragraph 6
dfOut = spark.read.format("iceberg").load("data_vault_lake.test.writeTest1")
display(dfOut)

error for paragraph 6:
UnsupportedOperationException: Byte-buffer read unsupported by org.apache.hadoop.fs.BufferedFSInputStream
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 47) (10.139.64.20 executor 1): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Byte-buffer read unsupported by org.apache.hadoop.fs.BufferedFSInputStream
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.read(FSDataInputStream.java:160)
    at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics.$anonfun$read$1(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:77)
    at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics.withTimeAndBytesReadMetric(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:67)
    at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics.read(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.read(FSDataInputStream.java:156)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.H2SeekableInputStream$H2Reader.read(H2SeekableInputStream.java:82)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.H2SeekableInputStream.readFully(H2SeekableInputStream.java:91)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.H2SeekableInputStream.readFully(H2SeekableInputStream.java:76)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:584)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.<init>(ParquetFileReader.java:799)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.open(ParquetFileReader.java:666)
    at org.apache.iceberg.parquet.ReadConf.newReader(ReadConf.java:238)
    at org.apache.iceberg.parquet.ReadConf.<init>(ReadConf.java:81)
    at org.apache.iceberg.parquet.VectorizedParquetReader.init(VectorizedParquetReader.java:90)
    at org.apache.iceberg.parquet.VectorizedParquetReader.iterator(VectorizedParquetReader.java:99)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.BatchDataReader.open(BatchDataReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.BatchDataReader.open(BatchDataReader.java:41)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.BaseReader.next(BaseReader.java:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.PartitionIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.MetricsIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1(DataSourceRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1$adapted(DataSourceRDD.scala:64)
    at scala.Option.exists(Option.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.advanceToNextIter(DataSourceRDD.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.$anonfun$encodeUnsafeRows$5(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:88)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.$anonfun$encodeUnsafeRows$3(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:88)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.$anonfun$encodeUnsafeRows$1(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:68)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$2(Collector.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$5(Task.scala:151)
    at com.databricks.unity.EmptyHandle$.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:145)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:961)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:853)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:3908)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:3830)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:3817)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:3817)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1695)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1680)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1680)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:4154)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:4066)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:4054)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$runJob$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1357)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1345)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:3000)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$runSparkJobs$1(Collector.scala:355)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$collect$1(Collector.scala:384)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$computeResult$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:546)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.collectResult$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:540)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.computeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$getOrComputeResultInternal$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:400)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResultInternal(ResultCacheManager.scala:400)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.qrc.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeCollectResult$1(SparkPlan.scala:558)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectResult(SparkPlan.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3780)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectResult$1(Dataset.scala:3771)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$3(Dataset.scala:4727)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:1103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4725)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId0$9(SQLExecution.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:700)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId0$1(SQLExecution.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:1175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId0(SQLExecution.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:637)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4725)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3770)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation0(OutputAggregator.scala:322)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation(OutputAggregator.scala:100)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.generateTableResult(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:848)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterDriverLocal.computeListResultsItem(JupyterDriverLocal.scala:1491)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterDriverLocal$JupyterEntryPoint.addCustomDisplayData(JupyterDriverLocal.scala:286)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:397)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:306)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:199)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Byte-buffer read unsupported by org.apache.hadoop.fs.BufferedFSInputStream
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.read(FSDataInputStream.java:160)
    at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics.$anonfun$read$1(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:77)
    at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics.withTimeAndBytesReadMetric(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:67)
    at com.databricks.spark.metrics.FSInputStreamWithMetrics.read(FileSystemWithMetrics.scala:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.read(FSDataInputStream.java:156)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.H2SeekableInputStream$H2Reader.read(H2SeekableInputStream.java:82)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.H2SeekableInputStream.readFully(H2SeekableInputStream.java:91)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.H2SeekableInputStream.readFully(H2SeekableInputStream.java:76)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:584)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.<init>(ParquetFileReader.java:799)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.open(ParquetFileReader.java:666)
    at org.apache.iceberg.parquet.ReadConf.newReader(ReadConf.java:238)
    at org.apache.iceberg.parquet.ReadConf.<init>(ReadConf.java:81)
    at org.apache.iceberg.parquet.VectorizedParquetReader.init(VectorizedParquetReader.java:90)
    at org.apache.iceberg.parquet.VectorizedParquetReader.iterator(VectorizedParquetReader.java:99)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.BatchDataReader.open(BatchDataReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.BatchDataReader.open(BatchDataReader.java:41)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.source.BaseReader.next(BaseReader.java:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.PartitionIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.MetricsIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1(DataSourceRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.$anonfun$hasNext$1$adapted(DataSourceRDD.scala:64)
    at scala.Option.exists(Option.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.advanceToNextIter(DataSourceRDD.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.$anonfun$encodeUnsafeRows$5(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:88)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.$anonfun$encodeUnsafeRows$3(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:88)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.$anonfun$encodeUnsafeRows$1(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:68)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$2(Collector.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$5(Task.scala:151)
    at com.databricks.unity.EmptyHandle$.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:145)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:961)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:853)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more


Can you try installing the org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.3_2.12:1.4.3 via Maven and check if it helps you?

we tried 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0. everything runs great in the databricks 12.2 lts runtime, but it's python version is 3.9. We are developing in 3.10 so we need to upgrade our databricks runtime version to get there.

Also, the 1.4.3 iceberg runtimes version's spark (3.3) is not compatible with the databricks 14.3 lts runtime (3.5)

The root cause is an issue with iceberg accessing the Byte Buffer Read stream through loki. That is unsupported for Apache Iceberg.
Updating our cluster configs to the following worked:

DB Runtime: 14.3 LTS (Scala 2.12, Spark 3.5)

Cluster Spark Config:

fs.azure org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem
spark.hadoop.fs.wasbs.impl
org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem
spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog
org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog fs.wasbs.impl
org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem spark.sql.extensions
org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions


Libraries: azure-storage:8.6.6 hadoop-azure:3.4.0
iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.5.2

We have a bug on the Iceberg project and once fixed this will be resolved: https://github.com/apache/iceberg/issues/10808
